# Submitting form whilst avoiding details and including list

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, list, user-interface

This might be hard to explain, but I have an input field which is designed to add "responsibilities" to a list when the add button is clicked. This works fine. This can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/VrGau/14/

The code for this is here:

```
var $responsibilityInput = $('#responsibilityInput'),
    $responsibilityList = $('#responsibilityList'),
    $inputButton = $('#add'),
    rCounter = 0;

var addResponsibility = function () {
    if (rCounter < 10) {
        var newVal = $responsibilityList.val() + $responsibilityInput.val();
        var newLi = $('<li>');
        $('ul#list').append(newLi.text(newVal));
        $responsibilityInput.val('');
    }
}

$inputButton.click(addResponsibility);
```

My question is, when I submit my form using the send button, I want to include the items in the list in my sumbmission, but at the same time not include the responsibilityList field which added the items to the list.

Comment: You could use hidden form elements

Comment: Is that really the only way I can include list items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use JQuery Ajax for this? this would look like:

```
var sendForm = function() {
    // Get item values
    var items = $.map($('ul#list>li'), function(n, i) {
        return $(n).text();
    });

    // Make Ajax Post
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "target.php",
      data: items
    });

    return false;
}

$submitButton = $("#send");
$submitButton.click(sendForm);
```

Does this help?